# Windows 10 Cannot pin some of the programs/folders to Start

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

Just upgraded from win 8.1 Pro.

I can pin some programs such as Chrome, Firefox, MS Visual Studio but a lot of other programs such as Steam, Paint.Net, Notepad++ or any folder shortcut do not get pinned. And I cannot find them via the search.

Also when I first launched Win 10 after upgrade there were a lot of items in the start menu (most of what I had in win 8.1), I started to rearrange them since they all were in one long group and noticed that some of the programs/folders are missing here, that is how I found the issue described above. So I thought that restart may fix this, I restarted my PC (+some update installed) and **most of the items in start menu disappeared**, only several default apps such as Weather, News, Edge remained. But after that I added some programs and restarted few times, have not encountered it again so far. The first issue is still not solved though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing clean install (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10), now it works fine.

I always knew that non-clean Windows upgrades suck :( Never even tried them before.